# Netsuite suitetalk transaction email with pdf attachment intro text

Tags: netsuite

I'm using php toolkit with netsuite to add a Sales order with the toBeEmailed option, and the api user it logs in with has the preference "Transaction Email Attachment Format" -> "PDF".

This causes the order summary to be made into a pdf and attached to an email and sent as a notification.

Ive looked and looked around netsuite admin and the api to see if there is any way i can customise/change/set the 'intro' text it puts into the email that carries the pdf attachment.

> Please open the attached file to view your {transaction form title}.
>
> To view the attachment, you first need the free Adobe Acrobat Reader.
>   If you don't have it yet, visit Adobe's Web site
>   http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/readstep.html to download it.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reply from support, is that this is not a feature yet, though has been requested.