# Where can I find the template of the email that is sent with the Invoice to a customer?

Tags: email, templates, netsuite

The customer in Netsuite gets an email with the generated invoice attached as a pdf. The requirement is to change the body of the email. I am unable to locate the template that has this info to modify. Please advise.
The current body of the email is:
"Please open the attached file to view your Invoice.

To view the attachment, you first need the free Adobe Acrobat Reader. If you don't have it yet, visit Adobe's Web site http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/readstep.html to download it."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
`Customize-->Transaction Forms-->Whichever invoice form you're using`.
```

Under this form you should be able to choose which email template to send. 
To find this email template,

```
Customize-->Transaction form PDF/HTML layouts
```

Under this menu you should be able to select and customize the email template however you want. Make sure the template you edit corresponds to the template that is showing on the form.

You may need to or have the desire to enable advanced/PDF/HTML templates, which allows you to edit and customize forms in a much more robust fasion using HTML/XML/CSS, Freemarker, and BFO. (See suiteanswers: 48703)

Comment: Thank you for answering.
I was able to locate the name of the "Email template" through Customization->Forms->Transactions and then opening the Invoice form.
But, I am unable to find the email template through Customization->form->advanced pdf/html templates and the template seen from before. I only see the design of the Invoice form but not the email being sent.

Comment: It looks like this may have been answered a few years ago. I doubt it's been added since then. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38237437/netsuite-suitetalk-transaction-email-with-pdf-attachment-intro-text

Comment: Got it. That was from 2016 and unfortunately there has been no solution as of today! Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I know the original post is several years old, but I too found myself searching for answers recently in stackoverflow so I thought I would post the answer to this questioon.

Use the global search bar to type in *Email Template*.  You can customize from there. I've attached a screenshot that replaces the generic message

*"Please open the attached file to view your Invoice.
To view the attachment, you first need the free Adobe Acrobat Reader. If you don't have it yet, visit Adobe's Web site http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/readstep.html to download it."*

It has been awhile since I found and got this email template to work, so it is possible there may be another section where you have to set the preference to use this customized email template.

[image]